# MySQL InnoDB: Assertion failure ibuf0ibuf.c line 4185 unrecoverable data crash

Tags: mysql, innodb

I get this assertion failure on MySQL 5.5.15 version.

Here are the MySQL server errors:

```
110927 21:56:51  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 1126107456 in file ibuf0ibuf.c line
4185
InnoDB: Failing assertion: page_get_n_recs(page) > 1
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
```

---

```
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
110927 21:56:51 - mysqld got signal 6 ;
```

---

```
key_buffer_size=536870912
read_buffer_size=4194304
max_used_connections=446
max_threads=2500
thread_count=341
connection_count=341
```

---

```
110927 21:56:54 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
110927 21:56:54 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
110927 21:56:54 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
110927 21:56:54 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
110927 21:56:54 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
110927 21:56:54 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 48.0G
110927 21:56:56 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
110927 21:56:56 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 2476542143668
110927 21:56:56  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 2476547386368
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 2476552629248
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 2476557872128
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 2476563115008
```

---

```
InnoDB: 45 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 45 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is E6B79400
110927 21:58:04  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 
110927 21:59:08  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 1104251200 in file ibuf0ibuf.c line
4185
InnoDB: Failing assertion: page_get_n_recs(page) > 1
```

---

After this error, MySQL couldn't recovery completely and MySQL server had been shut down.

I tried to do the InnoDB force recovery.
I couldn't recover crashed data using InnoDB force recovery level 0 to 3 but level 4.

It turned out I just can sqldump data.

As long as change one of a slavedb as a masterdb, my services out of service.

I'm afraid that the same or similar error will be able to repeat again on the new
masterdb.

---

The crashed MySQL server's my.cnf options:

```
max_allowed_packet = 1024M
net_buffer_length = 32768
binlog_cache_size = 16M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 64M
datadir = /data/mysql/data
table_cache = 2048
sort_buffer_size = 4M
read_buffer_size = 4M
join_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 4M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 4M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size = 1024M
query_cache_limit = 2M
thread_stack = 192K
thread_concurrency = 48
max_connections = 2500
max_connect_errors = 1000
max_heap_table_size = 64M
back_log = 200

innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb = on
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 48G
innodb_data_file_path = inno:1G:autoextend
innodb_data_home_dir = /data/mysql/data
innodb_thread_concurrency = 48
innodb_commit_concurrency = 48
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_log_file_size = 1024M
innodb_log_files_in_group = 3
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /data/mysql/data
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120
innodb_open_files = 102400
```

At the point time:

```
=== status ===
Threads: 354  Questions: 187502669  Slow queries: 209  Opens: 3150  Flush tables: 1  Open
tables: 617  Queries per second avg: 4089.301

top - 21:56:01 up 4 days, 20:59,  0 users,  load average: 5.05, 5.41, 5.64
Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.5%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 95.8%id,  2.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  98929268k total, 97815088k used,  1114180k free,   245976k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free, 40979780k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
26019 mysql     15   0 58.1g  52g 7012 S 321.8 55.5   1128:48 mysqld

*after mysql's crashed
=== status ===

top - 21:58:01 up 4 days, 21:01,  0 users,  load average: 2.47, 4.59, 5.33
Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.5%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 95.8%id,  2.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  98929268k total, 55021972k used, 43907296k free,   246568k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free, 40997228k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
13077 mysql     25   0 53.8g  11g 3904 D 86.0 12.3   1:06.61 mysqld
```

Comment: It looks like a bug: http://213.136.52.24/bug.php?id=61104

Comment: Start `mysqld` from `gdb` and send a bug report: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/crashing.html